# Limit being applied before order direction in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've come across a problem or bug where if I order by an associated column, and limit the results, they appear to be limited *first* and *then* ordered.

This doesn't happen when ordering by columns of the model I've queried, just the associated model's column. The order is also perfect if I don't limit the results at all.

**Practical example**:

`Job A (Company 2), Job B (Company 1), Job C (Company 4), Job D (Company 3)`

Ordering by `Company` name with no limit property gives the results: `B, A, D, C`, as expected

Adding a limit property of 3 seems to return the limited results: `A, B, C` and *then* orders them, resulting in `B, A, C`, when it should be `B, A, D`

Association:

```
Company.hasMany(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });
Job.belongsTo(Company, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });
```

Models:

```
const Company = sequelize.define('company', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    }
});

const Job = sequelize.define('job', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    // Lots more boring fields
});
```

Query & options object:

```
switch(req.query.orderField) {
    case 'company': {
        order = [ 
            'company', 'name', orderDirection
        ];
        break;
    }
    default:
        order = [ orderField, orderDirection ];
}

const options = {
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'title',   
        [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('job.createdAt'), '%d/%m/%y'), 'jobDate'],

    ],
    order: [ order ],
    distinct: true,
    include: [ 
        {
            model: Company,
            attributes: ['name'],
        },  
    ]
};


// Commenting out this line works fine
if(req.query.limit) options.limit = parseInt(limit, 10);
if(req.query.index) options.offset = parseInt(index);

const results = await Job.findAndCountAll(options);
```

I'm pretty stumped tbh, would really appreciate some help!

****Update**:

So in order to make the options model more concise, I left out one other included model: `Applicant`. So `Job` has an `include` with both a `Company` model and an `Applicant` model (with its own nested model).

It actually looks like this:

```
include: [ 
    {
        model: Company,
        attributes: ['name'],
    }, 
    {
        model: Applicant,
        attributes: [
            'id', 
            'cvUrl', 
            'personId',
            [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('applicants.createdAt'), '%d/%m/%y'), 'createdAt'],
        ],
        include: [ 
            {
                model: Person,
                attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'email' ]
            } 
        ] 
    }
]
```

I didn't think it would make any difference, but I checked out the query, and it does have a subquery: (TLDR for your convenience followed by real query)

**TLDR pseudo query:**

`SELECT job.* ... FROM(SELECT job.id ... FROM jobs AS job LIMIT 0 8) AS job ... JOINS HERE ORDER BY company.name ASC`

**Actual query:**

```
Executing (default): SELECT `job`.*, `company`.`id` AS `company.id`, `company`.`name` AS `company.name`, `applicants`.`id` AS `applicants.id`, `applicants`.`cvUrl` AS `applicants.cvUrl`, `applicants`.`personId` AS `applicants.personId`, date_format(`applicants`.`createdAt`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `applicants.createdAt`, `applicants->application`.`id` AS `applicants.application.id`, `applicants->application`.`createdAt` AS `applicants.application.createdAt`, `applicants->application`.`updatedAt` AS `applicants.application.updatedAt`, `applicants->application`.`applicantId` AS `applicants.application.applicantId`, `applicants->application`.`jobId` AS `applicants.application.jobId`, `applicants->person`.`id` AS `applicants.person.id`, `applicants->person`.`firstName` AS `applicants.person.firstName`, `applicants->person`.`lastName` AS `applicants.person.lastName`, `applicants->person`.`phone` AS `applicants.person.phone`, `applicants->person`.`email` AS `applicants.person.email` FROM (SELECT `job`.`id`, `job`.`title`, `job`.`wage`, `job`.`location`, `job`.`description`, `job`.`jobType`, `job`.`position`, `job`.`pqe`, `job`.`featured`, `job`.`createdAt`, date_format(`job`.`createdAt`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `jobDate`, `job`.`companyId` FROM `jobs` AS `job` LIMIT 0, 8) AS `job` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS `company` ON `job`.`companyId` = `company`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `applications` AS `applicants->application` INNER JOIN `applicants` AS `applicants` ON `applicants`.`id` = `applicants->application`.`applicantId`) ON `job`.`id` = `applicants->application`.`jobId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `people` AS `applicants->person` ON `applicants`.`personId` = `applicants->person`.`id` ORDER BY `company`.`name` ASC;
```

So it is limiting the results first.

But here's the fix: **Removing the included `Applicant` model**:

(This query isn't so bad)

```
Executing (default): SELECT `job`.`id`, `job`.`title`, `job`.`wage`, `job`.`location`, `job`.`description`, `job`.`jobType`, `job`.`position`, `job`.`pqe`, `job`.`featured`, `job`.`createdAt`, date_format(`job`.`createdAt`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `jobDate`, `job`.`companyId`, `company`.`id` AS `company.id`, `company`.`name` AS `company.name` FROM `jobs` AS `job` LEFT OUTER JOIN `companies` AS `company` ON `job`.`companyId` = `company`.`id` ORDER BY `company`.`name` ASC LIMIT 0, 8;
```

But I can't work out why that included `Applicant` would fix the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend to log the query that is generated using say `options.logging = console.log` and check if the query looks as expected and the RDBMS returns the expected result.

Comment: Did you try `subQuery: false`?

Comment: @Anatoly - I now have, thanks, but that seems to limit my results arbitrarily to 3 (when there are 5 entries at the moment)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm just going through it now, but I seem to have created quite a convoluted query, and my SQL is pretty rusty.

Comment: @Anatoly you were right - it was doing (what looks to me like) a subquery. I've updated the OP, but TLDR: I actually had two included models, one that I left out to be concise. Leaving it out somehow fixes the problem?!

Comment: In such cases it's very important to indicate all included models and their associations

Comment: I just didn't think it would have an impact! Good to know though, I will do in the future. Have you any idea how to include that model without the problem occuring? It's unfortunately a stop gap at best for me